# Tomlison's assertion on raster and vector data

Tags: arcgis-10.0

Discuss Tomlinson's assertion that "raster is simpler and raster is faster but vector is more correcter"

Comment: This isn't really a question.  Feel free to re-open this if you can formulate it as a (non-argumentative) question.

Comment: Perhaps word it as "What does Tomlinson mean by his assertion that "raster is simpler and raster is faster but vector is more correcter" and is this correct today?" You might add a tag of GIScience or something similar. Also a reference to where he states the assertion might be nice for people to go read.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-to-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: Sounds like homework.

Comment: Indeed .... someones looking for a copy/paste special for a homework assignment!!

Answer (score 5):

If the eyes are a raster device, do vectors even exist - or are they an optical illusion?

From [Starizona article](http://starizona.com/acb/basics/observing_theory.aspx):

> The eye can be thought of as analogous
>   to a telescope.  The lens focuses
>   light onto the retina, just as a
>   telescope lens would focus light onto
>   a focal plane.  Putting a camera at
>   the telescope's focal plane captures
>   the light just as the eye's retina
>   does.  And like a digital camera or
>   CCD, the retina is divided into
>   "pixels" made up of light-sensitive
>   cells called rods and cones.

[image]

Comment: Forgive my slowness, but I'm not sure what you're getting at.

Comment: Sorry, I should have made my sarcasm more clear.  I was alluding to Maslow's [Law of the Instrument](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_instrument) "_It is tempting, if the only tool you have is a hammer, to treat everything as if it were a nail._"

Comment: Well played, Kirk.